# Is there anyway to get VKdebug output if program works?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

If my program works I don't get `VKdebug` window, and I can't find out how to make it open or for `vk` to write it down in a file.

I'm using `PrintHex` and `PrintDec` commands from `debug.inc` file.

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake. There was a bug in my code that ended the program before any of vkdebug functions. With that fixed VK will open every time I open the program.